# Memory resources not being released in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app and I'm having an issue with releasing resources from a file stream. The problem happens when I access the isolated storage to get an image, and then I set the image to an image source on the view; this all happens when the page loads. (I'm using the Windows Phone Application Analysis tool to view the memory usage). Also, whenever I close and reopen the page in the app, the memory usage continues to increase.

This is my code to get the image and set it:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("background.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BitmapImage imageFile = new BitmapImage();
    imageFile.SetSource(fileStream);
    BackgroundImage.ImageSource = imageFile;

    // tried using .Close() but it wasn't releasing the resources as well. 
    fileStream.Dispose();
}
```

Is there something else I should be doing to properly release the resources?

**EDIT**

I realized my problem... When the app first starts I have it setting the same image that I'm opening in the code above. So when I open a new page with the same image, it seems to not be releasing the existing file stream resources because it's opening the same file over and over again. The fix was to add a BitMapImage property in my View Model that I can access whenever I need without having to constantly grab the file in the isolated storage.

Thanks for all the help from everyone

Comment: Are you sure that the above code makes the problem? Is there any other codes in your page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose the IsolatedStorageFile, too.  This should work (though I didn't compile it)

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("background.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BitmapImage imageFile = new BitmapImage();
    imageFile.SetSource(fileStream);
    BackgroundImage.ImageSource = imageFile;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, still same problem. It actually crashes if I close and reopen the page more than 3 times due to the little amount of memory available. Could this be an issue with how windows phone handles releasing it's resources between page navigation?

Comment: The above code will certainly dispose the resources.  So maybe the crash is due to some other reason?  Do you see any error messages, e.g, in the Debug output window?  If the crash is due to an exception, can you set debugger to break when exception is thrown (shows more of the relevant context)?

Comment: I absolutely agree, I did some debugging and it crashes on this line: "imageFile.SetSource(fileStream);". The exception is an OutOfMemoryException

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Source propety instead of ImageSource:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("background.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BitmapImage imageFile = new BitmapImage();
    imageFile.SetSource(fileStream);
    BackgroundImage.Source= imageFile;
}
}
```

Comment: I have to use ImageSource because I'm setting the image to an ImageBrush on the view.